# What is the correct way to check if the VPN connection is actually used (PHP CLI)?

Tags: php, windows, openvpn

I run a PHP CLI script. Before doing anything, I want to make sure that the VPN connection is used. Sometimes, it doesn't connect on startup, and sometimes, it goes down randomly after first being active.

I want to be able to detect this from PHP CLI.

Is there a way other than constantly making requests to a remote server which reports my hostname, and then check whether it contains some known domain/string? That "solution" would soon get me in trouble due to the constant (one every minute) checks whether or not the connection is still using the VPN.

I cannot run my own server to have such a service just for me.

The PC on which I'm trying to check this is located in a home, behind a NAT router, if that matters. It runs OpenVPN, which to my knowledge doesn't provide any kind of useful "local API" which would allow me to ask it if the connection is still active, etc.

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Couldn't you use the result of ifconfig/ipconfig command?  I guess if the VPN is connected, you would see some ppp connection.

Comment: ipconfig only shows the internal IP address/hostname -- not the actual one. Also, I don't know what "ppp" means in this context?

Comment: Certainly the IP range of the client changes when using the VPN connection.

Comment: @arkascha Hmm. The "IP range of the client"? Can you elaborate?